# Webscraping website that has a button to click

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to webscrape a website that has multiple javascript rendered pages (https://openlibrary.ecampusontario.ca/catalogue/).  I am able to get the content from the first page, but I am not sure how to get my script to click on the buttons on the subsequent pages to get that content.  Here is my script.

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import json

# The path to where you have your chrome webdriver stored:
webdriver_path = '/Users/rawlins/Downloads/chromedriver'

# Add arguments telling Selenium to not actually open a window
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1920x1080')

# Fire up the headless browser
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = webdriver_path,
chrome_options = chrome_options)

# Load webpage
url = "https://openlibrary.ecampusontario.ca/catalogue/"
browser.get(url)

# to ensure that the page has loaded completely.
time.sleep(3)

data = [] 

# Parse HTML, close browser
page_soup = soup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"result-item tooltip"})

for container in containers:
    item = {}
    item['type'] = "Textbook"
    item['title'] = container.find('h4', {'class' : 'textbook-title'}).text.strip()
    item['author'] = container.find('p', {'class' : 'textbook-authors'}).text.strip()
    item['link'] = "https://openlibrary.ecampusontario.ca/catalogue/" + container.find('h4', {'class' : 'textbook-title'}).a["href"]
    item['source'] = "eCampus Ontario"
    item['base_url'] = "https://openlibrary.ecampusontario.ca/catalogue/"
    data.append(item) # add the item to the list

with open("js-webscrape-2.json", "w") as writeJSON:
    json.dump(data, writeJSON, ensure_ascii=False)

browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to actually click on any button. For example, to search for items with the keyword 'electricity', you navigate to the url

```
https://openlibrary-repo.ecampusontario.ca/rest/filtered-items?query_field%5B%5D=*&query_op%5B%5D=matches&query_val%5B%5D=(%3Fi)electricity&filters=is_not_withdrawn&offset=0&limit=10000
```

This will return a json string of items with the first item being:

```
{"items":[{"uuid":"6af61402-b0ec-40b1-ace2-1aa674c2de9f","name":"Introduction to Electricity, Magnetism, and Circuits","handle":"123456789/579","type":"item","expand":["metadata","parentCollection","parentCollectionList","parentCommunityList","bitstreams","all"],"lastModified":"2019-05-09 15:51:06.91","parentCollection":null,"parentCollectionList":null,"parentCommunityList":null,"bitstreams":null,"withdrawn":"false","archived":"true","link":"/rest/items/6af61402-b0ec-40b1-ace2-1aa674c2de9f","metadata":null}, ...
```

Now, to get that item, you use its uuid, and navigate to:

```
https://openlibrary.ecampusontario.ca/catalogue/item/?id=6af61402-b0ec-40b1-ace2-1aa674c2de9f
```

You can proceed like this for any interaction with that website (this is not always working for all websites, but it is working for your website).

To find out what are the urls that are navigated to when you click such and such button or enter text (what I did for the above urls), you can use [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

Answer (score 0):

I made a little script that can help you (selenium).

what this script does is "while the last page of the catalogue is not selected (in this case, contain 'selected' in it's class), i'll **scrape** , then click next"

```
while "selected" not in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[id='results-pagecounter-pages'] a")[-1].get_attribute("class"):
    #your scraping here
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[id='next-btn']").click()
```

There's probably a problem that you'll run into using this method, it doesn't wait for the results to load, but you can figure out what to do from here onwards.

Hope it helps